# mouseover effect in touch devices

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, touch

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve a 'mouseover' effect in touch devices.

I've created this simple example to demonstrate the behavior i'm looking for.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    isDown = false;

    $('#rect1').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        isDown = true;

        $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
    });

    $(document).on('touchend mouseup', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        isDown = false;

        $('#rect1').css({'background-color':'grey'});
        $('#rect2').css({'background-color':'grey'});
    });

    $('#rect2').on('touchmove mouseover', function(e) {//.hover(function() {
        if (isDown) {
            $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mE9Ug/

I want to achieve the same behavior on mobile (touch devices).

as you can see (in the example), touchmove wont work. i also tried jquery mobile's vmouseover which doesn't work as well.

if someone has any ideas i'd really appreciate it!

thanks,
Asaf

Comment: if u able to check console then first u should check your console error ..i m sure console errors are destroy your hover effect....

Comment: What do you mean? in my mobile i dont have a console option, and there's no error on the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick on iOS devices : http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/making-mouseover-event-work-on-an-ipad/